# How to redirect apache public url to docker container?

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, apache2, ubuntu-18.04, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a webapi project that is located inside a Docker container. A self-signed certificate is available and connected to Apache. When contacting the address https://server_ip/ I get a test page Apache with information that everything works correctly. Docker without Apache also works correctly when requested http://server_ip/controller_name I get the correct response. How can I make user requests at https://server_ip/controller_name redirect to docker container?

Edit: Help me please :(

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-redirect-apache-public-url-to-docker-container

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work for me